# jQuery .load() call doesn't work in Firefox - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

I'm a newbie programmer working with jQuery and wonder if anyone can help me out.

Essentially, I've created some html for a social button's section on our articles.

I've uploaded that with the aim of using jQuery's .load() function to pull it into every article.

It works in IE7, but not in Firefox or Chrome. Can anyone help fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#shareBlock').load("http://i.thisis.co.uk/275563/binaries/sharebox.html");

});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you installed firebug into firefox? Use the net panel to see whats going on...

Comment: If its a same origin problem, IE will work but show a security warning. Firefox and Chrome will fail silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the URL in your `load()` and the nature of the issue I believe you have a problem with same origin. If your URL is external/violates same origin in some way you will not be able to load it in this manner.

For more details check this out - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: What is the URL of the site that you are making the request FROM?

Comment: There wasn't a security warning in IE, but the div was replaced. I'll have a go at hosting both pages on the same URL to see if that works

Comment: I was just testing it from page saved on Dropbox. I suspect that might be the reason. I'll put the share html and the script on the same domain. Hopefully that should work. :) The learning from journalist to coder is proving fairly steep. Thank God for websites like this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please show me how did you load jquery library in `<head>`?

I had the same problem and I solved it by repacing `/>` to end script tag with `</script>` end tag.

More here: http://javaxtendsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/jquery-doesnt-load-in-firefox/